# Can any database table name support double quotes "?

Tags: jdbc, sql-standard, naming-convention

I need to know whether any database supports double quotes as a part of their table name. I am especially interested in JDBC compliant databases. And if they do, can I please know how?

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Double-quote char have special meaning, so when you want to use it as a common char you must quote it. The quoting method is dependent by DBMS. It can be quoting by slash or another symbol, doubling, wrapping... Of course, some DBMSs may not allow that at all.

Answer (score 5):

According to the SQL standard, this should be possible by doubling the double quotes (similar to escaping single quotes in string constants).

At least Postgres does support this (and Oracle does not, resulting in "*ORA-03001: unimplemented feature*")

```
create table "really""stupid_name"(id integer);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JYCW13692

---

However, using quoted identifiers is a bad idea to begin with. Let alone identifiers that in turn contain double quotes.

I would strongly suggest you do **not** do this.

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL also support this nonsense! [SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5e85e92bad5ebda002b7974f8472c97), [MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8982d80c40b30b7234b9dd3c752f388)

Comment: But [SQLite is **awesome**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=3443658e0e62d0f73aac9993525222a1)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: actually I find it quite sad, that SQLite gives in and accepts all non-standard identifier types when the rules for SQL identifiers have been laid out more than 30 years ago - pre dating all those DBMS that chose to ignore that.

Comment: Yeah. SQLite and MySQL especially have a very weird approach to handling string literals and identifiers (essentially allowing them to being mixed up freely in almost all cases).

Answer (score 2):

```
Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE `test"d"quote` (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)

mysql> insert into `test"d"quote` values (1), (11);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from `test"d"quote`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|   11 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table `test"d"quote`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)
```